# How to add several std_logic_vectors efficiently in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I'm using VHDL to create a simple code that can add several vectors.
For example, there is a vector (signal) A and B as below figure.

[image]

What I want to do is get all portion of A and add all of it. The result is then stored in B. Below figure is an example.
[image]

The easiest way is just listing every addition as below code

```vhdl
-- other codes

signal A: std_logic_vector(11 downto 0) := "100101011000";
signal B: std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);

-- other codes

B <= std_logic_vector(
unsigned(A(11 downto 9))
+ unsigned(A(8 downto 6))
+ unsigned(A(5 downto 3))
+ unsigned(A(2 downto 0))
);

-- other codes
```

However, above method could be inefficient when A and B becomes very large. Is there an efficient way to create an equivalent code? ( Maybe using generate form? ) 
Thanks for your advice.

Comment: You don't need a generate. A standard FOR-loop will work fine.

Comment: I tried the for-loop but I think it's not applicable in this case. Is there an another method other than the standard For-loop?

Comment: I am at work and don't have time for a full example. You need to re-write your code to remove the outer 'std_logic_vector'. e.g. use an interim variable which is unsigned , add to that in a loop, then back to B.

Comment: there is no reason to use `std_logic` first place, this just makes your code difficult to read and understand. When you want to do arithmetics in VHDL, use `unsigned`, `signed` or even `integer` types. Makes your life a lot easier.